# transitive-closure-table example

Tags: android, sqlite, transitive-closure-table

I know that transitive-closure concept is used for storing tree structures data.
This concept also used to retrieve hierarchical data in very efficient and quickly with minimum complex query.

In SQLite Query browser, I have tried these queries:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    parent_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id)
); 

CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE category_closure USING transitive_closure (
    tablename="category",
    idcolumn="id",
    parentcolumn="parent_id"
);
```

I am able to create table using query no. 1 but query no. 2 is not working.

Can someone provide specific example in Android using SQLite?

Comment: SQLite understands standard SQL. What is the problem?

Comment: @CL. in SQLite Query browser, I have fired below queries. 1.    CREATE TABLE category (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  parent_id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES category (id));

2. CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE category_closure USING transitive_closure (
  tablename="category",
  idcolumn="id",
  parentcolumn="parent_id"); I can able to create table using query no. 1 but query no. 2 is not working. can you please look into it?

Comment: Where did you learn about the `transitive_closure` module? It is neither standard SQL, nor part of the Android API. You have to do all the queries manually.

Comment: I have found while reading this blog http://charlesleifer.com/blog/querying-tree-structures-in-sqlite-using-python-and-the-transitive-closure-extension/ also on sqlite official site http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/636024302cde41b2bf0c542f81c40c624cfb7012 Please have a look and let me know your feedback for the same.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the blog post [Querying Tree Structures in SQLite using Python and the Transitive Closure Extension](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/querying-tree-structures-in-sqlite-using-python-and-the-transitive-closure-extension/), the [transitive closure extension](http://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/636024302cde41b2bf0c542f81c40c624cfb7012) must be compiled manually.
This is not possible when using the default Android database API.

You could [use triggers to maintain an explicit closure table](http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html).